# How to set the date in beamer notes?

Tags: beamer, notes, date

Is there a way to set an specific date (e.g. the presentation date) in beamer's notes?

Using `\date{some date}` has no effect in the notes. Only the compilation date is shown.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compilation date is stored in `\day`, `\month` and `\year`. Without testing due to the lack of a MWE I therefore postulate that you might change the date shown with the following:

```
\day=24\relax
\month=12\relax
\year=0\relax
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Somehow I thought the real date was related to `\date{}` and I see now it was a nonsense. Thanks for the real simple solution.

Comment: @Jander then maybe you should accept my answer. I think after a full day it is unlikely that there will pop-up a much better answer in the next few hours.

Comment: I thought I did... It's done now :)  Thanks for pointing out.